# Hibernate HQL Query : How to properly use ANY function in where clause?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm struggling to understand my error in an HQL query:

```
public List<Pats> getIds(List<String> patIds) {
    Session session = getSession();
    String hql = "from OurPats where patId = any (:patIds)";
    // String hql = "from OurPats where patId in (:patIds)";
    return session.createQuery(hql).setParameterList("patIds", patIds).list();
}
```

...the commented out line works properly, but I want the functionality of the non-working ANY comparison as patIds.size() can be greater than 2^15 (causing postgresql to break).

Judging from http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html the ANY function should work. In other forum questions people say not to use the elements function as is stipulated in the above link (I've tried with elements and I get an IDENT error). The above code produces an org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: : error.

Any ideas? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, `= ANY` is equivalent to `IN` (and I think they will be transformed into the same queries by the optimizer). From the PostgreSQL documentation:

> #### [9.16.4. ANY/SOME](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-subquery.html#AEN13969)
>
> ```
> expression operator ANY (subquery)
> expression operator SOME (subquery)
> ```
>
> The right-hand side is a parenthesized
>   subquery, which must return exactly
>   one column. The left-hand expression
>   is evaluated and compared to each row
>   of the subquery result using the given
>   `operator`, which must yield a Boolean
>   result. The result of `ANY` is "true"
>   if any true result is obtained. The
>   result is "false" if no true result is
>   found (including the special case
>   where the subquery returns no rows).
>
> `SOME` is a synonym for `ANY`. **`IN` is
>   equivalent to `= ANY`**.

So I don't think using `= ANY` will solve your problem anyway.

Of course, I don't have the context but are you sure that performing more than 2^15 `OR` comparisons really makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by wanting the functionality of 'any' rather than 'in.'  Every DBMS I know treats them as synonymous.

= ANY is not allowed for lists in MySQL, only for subqueries.  Ostensibly you have your dialect set to MySQL and Hibernate knows this?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html

> IN and = ANY are not synonyms when
>   used with an expression list. IN can
>   take an expression list, but = ANY
>   cannot. See Section 11.3.2,
>   “Comparison Functions and Operators”.

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL, so http://bit.ly/9ObRdJ is more appropriate. That's got me looking...

"expression IN (value [, ...])

The right-hand side is a parenthesized list of scalar expressions."

"expression operator ANY (array expression)

The right-hand side is a parenthesized expression, which must yield an array value."

perhaps if I modify this:
    return session.createQuery(hql).setParameterList("patIds", patIds).list();
to this:
    return session.createQuery(hql).setParameterList("patIds", patIds.toArray()).list();

...it will work? Nope. Same error. Hmm

Comment: huh, dunno how I got mySQL in my head, must have been reading two pages at once.  Perhaps your dialect isn't set to postgres and hibernate doesn't know to do the funky ARRAY['foo','bar'] thing?  you can set the hibernate.show_sql property to true or turn logging on package org.hibernate.SQL up to debug to see what it's actually sending to postgres