# HQL query checking each item of list against multiple requirements

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I want to filter a query based on the contents of a list on the entity. I do not simply want to check if something is in this list, I want to have a 'predicate' as in functional programming, It's been challenging to research since 'predicate' is something else in hql.

so basically

```
list.filter(x -> x > 100 and x < 150)
```

Is what I want in my hql.

```
// This query is pseudocode of what I want to achieve
// keywords ANY_OF, CONFORMS_TO are made up syntax in the code below
public List<PainTracker> getTrackersInCurrentlyActive() {
    String query = "FROM PainTracker AS tracker WHERE ANY_OF tracker.timePeriods AS tp CONFORMS_TO tp.startTime < :currentTime AND tp.endTime > :currentTime)";
    TypedQuery<ParkedParking> q = entityManager.createQuery(query, ParkedParking.class);
    q.setParameter("currentTime", new Date());
    return q.getResultList();
}

//PainTracker has this field 
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "pain_time_periods",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "pain_tracker"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "time_periods"))
private List<TimePeriod> timePeriods;

@Entity
@Table(name = "time_period")
public class TimePeriod {
// This table have startTime and endTime
```

I've looked at using [expression operator ANY (subquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267138/hibernate-hql-query-how-to-properly-use-any-function-in-where-clause) but I don't see how it gets all the way there. I need to have my entire expression as a check against each item in the list.

Does HQL have something for this, what is it called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the following query:

```
select distinct p from PainTracker p
join fetch p.timePeriods tp
where tp.startTime < :currentTime and tp.endTime > :currentTime
```

See also [this section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-implicit-join) of the hibernate documentation.

Comment: Hmm I got something like it up and running now. But I think it fails for my usecase: not stated in the question but I also have a where statement which basically is "WHERE p.timePeriods is empty OR <the thing the question describes>", and i suspect, that what happens is that 'is empty' can never be true with that join fetch the query is written?

Comment: Yes, but you can use `left join fetch` for this case.